# clearing a div using $('#DivId').html('')?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a webpage and a webgrid on that webpage, there is a 'Add' button that provides option for the user to add more records to that webgrid using a popup, there is also 'Edit' option for every row on the webgrid and the fields and model properties for 'Add' and 'Edit' popups are same...

I did some validation using jquery for the fields, if all the fields contain some data then only the 'Save' button will be enabled in both 'Add' and 'Edit' popups, if any of the field is empty then the save button will be disabled

The problem is when the user opens the 'Add Record' popup and closes the popup without entering any data and then when he opens the 'Edit Record' popup the 'Save' button is being disabled even after containing all the fields...

so i just cleared the 'AddUserDiv' on cancel button click with this

```
 $('#DivAddUser').html('');
```

this cleared the previous issue, but its creating a new issue, when i open the 'Add Record' popup for the second time, the empty popup is being opened and no controls on it

when i refresh the page and click the 'Add Record' popup then everything workds fine for the first time

Comment: Try to use `$('#DivAddUser').hide();`

Comment: @PiLHA using this im not able to open the popup for the second time

Comment: Try this one $('#DivAddUser').empty();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you have cleared the HTML using

```
$('#DivAddUser').html('');
```

it will remain cleared unless you assign new HTML to it, so, as expected your previous layout would not be visible.

so, what you need to do is to clear/reset the values of all the elements inside the div.

EDIT: based on your comment

you can store your previous HTML in a variable, before calling the above clear function as

```
previousHTML = $('#DivAddUser').html()
//should be done just once in the beginning
```

and then call

```
$('#DivAddUser').html('');
```

and then on showing 'Add Record' popup you set

```
 $('#DivAddUser').html(previousHTML);
```

but please keep in mind this is not the right way to clear values from a HTML page. you should write a clear() function, in which you should refer to every element on the page and explicitly clear or set the value to default.

Comment: how can i make previous HTML visible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the input fields using `$('#elementID').val('');` 
if you use `.html('')` it will clear the html inside that div